# Text to be in two lines when it is too long

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using constraint layout, Text `configHeading` due to translation can be long, if so I want it to be in two lines and not go under the switch

[image]

```
    ConstraintLayout {
    val (icon, configHeading, enableConfigRequestsSwitch, configDescription) = createRefs()
    Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_config_requests),
            tint = Color.White,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(icon) {
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    }
                    .padding(end = 10.dp)
    )
    Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.charger_advanced_settings_enable_config_requests),
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(configHeading) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(icon.end)
            }
    )
    Switch(
            checked = state.isAllowInstallerMode,
            onCheckedChange = onAllowInstallerModeChanged,
            colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(
                    checkedThumbColor = Color.White,
                    checkedTrackColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    uncheckedThumbColor = Color.White,
                    uncheckedTrackColor = Color.LightGray
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(enableConfigRequestsSwitch) {
                        top.linkTo(icon.top)
                        bottom.linkTo(icon.bottom)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    }
    )
    Text(
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelLarge,
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.charger_advanced_settings_allow_request_access_desc),
            color = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(configDescription) {
                        top.linkTo(configHeading.bottom)
                        start.linkTo(configHeading.start)
                    }
                    .padding(
                            top = 16.dp,
                            end = 16.dp
                    )
    )
}
```

Also padding 16.dp for `configDescription` does not work, I do not want the description to go past the end of the switch

How can I do this please

apologies there are two question in one.

thanks
R

Comment: Have you tried binding the right border of the Text to the left border of the Switch and specify maxLines > 1 then set overflow and softWrap accordingly ?

Answer (score 2):

try to add some more constraint to the end->>

```
Text(
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
    text = stringResource(id = R.string.charger_advanced_settings_enable_config_requests),
    color = Color.White,
    modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(configHeading) {
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        start.linkTo(icon.end)
        end.linkTo(enableConfigRequestsSwitch.start) // New constraint 
   

 }
)
```

hope it works for you :)

Comment: hello Ayush, adding an end will centre the text if the text is smaller, I always want it to start after icon

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to the answer by Ayush, please try to use [`fillToContraints`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/constraintlayout/compose/Dimension#fillToConstraints()):

```
Text(
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
    text = stringResource(id = R.string.charger_advanced_settings_enable_config_requests),
    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
    color = Color.White,
    modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(configHeading) {
        top.linkTo(parent.top)
        start.linkTo(icon.end)
        end.linkTo(enableConfigRequestsSwitch.start)
        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints  // fill between constraints
    }
)
```